# Error when echoing image php

Tags: php, mysql, image, post

I'm trying to echo out an image when a user post a php form.

The code looks like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<div>";
        echo "<h3>" . $row["who"] . "</h3></br>";
        echo "<h4>" . $row["what"] . "</h4></br>";
        echo "<h4>" . $row["where"] . "</h4></br>";
        echo "<h3>" . $row["contact"] . "</h3></br>";
        echo "<img src="../img/share_fb.gif"> ";
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

When when I refresh the page, nothing happens. It's just white.

Please help me fix this!

Comment: Change `echo "<img src="../img/share_fb.gif"> ";` to `echo "<img src=\"../img/share_fb.gif\"> ";`

Comment: It's a parse error, you have unescaped double quotes. Change to: `echo '<img src="../img/share_fb.gif">';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a errors - `</br>` should be `<br />`, and you need to escape your double quotes in your img `<img src="../img/share_fb.gif">`

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<div>";
        echo "<h3>" . $row["who"] . "</h3><br />";
        echo "<h4>" . $row["what"] . "</h4><br />";
        echo "<h4>" . $row["where"] . "</h4><br />";
        echo "<h3>" . $row["contact"] . "</h3><br />";
        echo "<img src=\"../img/share_fb.gif\"> ";
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

`echo "<img src="../img/share_fb.gif"> ";`

to

`echo "<img src=\"../img/share_fb.gif\"> ";`